# Adding wsdl web reference in asp .Net Core project

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I've got web service http://www.mcommunicator.ru/m2m/m2m_api.asmx?WSDL
And I've got a problem with connecting to it from Visual Studio 2015
in my Web API project

There is no "Add web reference" anymore
I've tried to add is with:
References-> Add connected Service -> WCF Service - Preview
It finds 1 web service by my address, but I get an error when click finish.
I guess it's not a WCF service, that's why I get an error.
But I don't see any other ways to add it. Please, help me.

Comment: You may be better off using a SOAP client, there's [probably plenty on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=soap).

Comment: I would rather work the old way, if it's possible. It was really convinient for me. Most of these packages have examples for mvc 4 not even 5 and i'm not 100% sure they will work with .net core. But I will try some, thanks for   advise.

Comment: @Soren that's a broken link...

Comment: take a look at [Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide) (it's now part of the Visual Studio)

Answer (score 44):

To add the SOAP service references for clients built on top of WCF for .NET Core 1.0 install the extension **Visual studio WCF Connected Service**  via the “Extensions and Updates” dialog box.

After installed, In Solution Explorer, right-click on the References project item and then click on the Add Connected Service option.

The Add Connected Service dialog box appears and you should have a new option "WCF Service - Preview".

Comment: @BhargavRao thank you for providing the link. hopefully the answer is better now.

Comment: Yeah, It's better. Deleted my commented and upvoted your post

Comment: have you tried to add soap service yourself? I've seen this article you're providing long before I wrote this question. And if you just red my question you would see that i've tried to do what article sujested andf failed

Comment: @el_konor Yes. I've tried it, I ran into this issue due to the fact that i was trying to do the same. You only see the azure storage option?

Comment: no, i press "wcf preview". Then I put web reference in address field  and click "Discover". It says  Number of services found: 0. If I click "go" visual studio finds something and then i try different combinations of datatype options and allways get an error "Attempting to download metadata from 'http://xxxxx.asmx' using WS-Metadata Exchange and HttpGet.
Generating files...  Updating project.json file ..." and   then i get "can not assess file"

Comment: I was getting that URI error when I clicked discover. I moved the WSDL file to  the root C: and it worked.

Comment: now it is "Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider" https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WCFCORETEAM.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService
Warning: there are bug in version from "Extensions and Updates" : https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2076#issuecomment-315934164
Version from MarketPlase is OK

Comment: @AProgrammer is there any plugin for vs code to add this plugin ? we should install vsudio 2017?

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi no there isn't, I needed it for BankMellat gateway and after 2 weeks i wrote my own, if you need this for BankMellat send me an email i will response with codes. email: mrsadin@Gmail.com

Comment: is the extension still available in 2020? i cannot find it in vs2019(community).

Comment: It seems this no longer needs an extension and is supported by VS2017 and later: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide