# WCF reference in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, .net-core

how can I reference WCF to my .NET Core client? I download and install  "WCF Service Preview" plugin but when I trying add reference I got error

> Error: No endpoints compatible with .Net Core apps were found.
>   An error occurred in the tool.
>
> Failed to generate service reference.

[image]

When I try service in my browser, works fine. Any ideas ?
My WCF's web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ServiceLayer.TeamManagementService" behaviorConfiguration="GetDataBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceLayer.ITeamManagementService" behaviorConfiguration="GetDataEndpointBehavior"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="GetDataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="GetDataEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Microsoft has moved all its focus to Visual Studio 2017 RC for .NET Core. You should try to generate a reference via that instead of working in VS2015, which is abandoned.

Comment: You can find the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39895385/1520221

Comment: Are you trying to host a service in WCF in .net core? Or are you trying to consume a WCF service from .net core code?

Answer (score 4):

Uncheck `Reuse types in referenced assemblies`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem a couple of days ago and could not find a specific reason to why the endpoint was not recognized correctly by the extension. I solved this by creating a class library project that includes a proxy for the actual WCF service. The NET Core project can then reference this project and indirectly call the service without connected references.

If you haven't found a solution to the problem yet, have a look at my github repository to see an example:
https://github.com/jolmari/netcore-wcf-service-proxy

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." - please post [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle there is no apparent relationship between your comment and the users *answer* (it's not even a question!).  Was this just a copy/paste error?  +1 For your politeness and apparent attempt to help, though... :)

Comment: This answer actually saved my day, after hours of troubleshooting finally proxy class library(net framework) saved me, because I was not able to reference old wcf service(written in net framework 4.0) into net core 2.1 wep API app. Thank you man a lot. It's been 4 years after your answer but I can say now you can safely ignore this stupid comments above mine

Comment: I'm glad the answer was helpful! The answer here is correct in situations where the tooling cannot generate the service references in .NET Core due to some structural issues, I could not figure out what was the actual reason. In the end the only solution was to write the custom approach demonstrated in the GitHub project.