# Consuming WCF via my application. I get Reference endpoints warning

Tags: android, wcf, iis, web-config

For my .Net Standart 2.0 MVVM project I try to add a reference to my Restful WCF service (IIS Express) but I get a warning, stating that 0 endpoints were found. As for the WCF server, everything seems to work. I also use Entity framework. What might be the problem? 
I'll add part of the web.config file and also the warning.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework"
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
             requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext"
         value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <!--1CHANGED-->
    <services>

      <service name="MoodWcfService.Services.UserService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  behaviorConfiguration="UserService_Behavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="MoodWcfService.IServices.IUserService" >
        </endpoint>
      </service>

      <service name="MoodWcfService.Services.RestaurantService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  behaviorConfiguration="RestaurantService_Behavior" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="MoodWcfService.IServices.IRestaurantService" >
        </endpoint>
      </service>

      <service name="MoodWcfService.Services.EvaluationService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  behaviorConfiguration="EvaluationService_Behavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="MoodWcfService.IServices.IEvaluationService" >
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" 
                           httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>

        <behavior name="UserService_Behavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled ="true"/>
        </behavior>

        <behavior name="RestaurantService_Behavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled ="true"/>
        </behavior>

        <behavior name="EvaluationService_Behavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled ="true"/>
        </behavior>

      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!--1CHANGED-->

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                               multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

[Warning while adding a service reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6zSm.png)

Comment: you can ignore this warning in this case if it's working for you. It looks like it's showing up because your WSDL does not contain any information about your endpoint.you could refer some git hub issue link: [link1](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2434) ,[link2](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3565) , [linl3](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3371) ,[link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075720/wcf-reference-in-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

At first, by default, the WCF service created by WebHttpBindig cannot be consumed by adding service reference menu. This kind of service is called the WCF Web service (REST API).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-wcf-web-http-service
By default, it doesn’t support for calling the service from client proxy class or channel factory. Because the Rest API has own method of addressing the path. Therefore, in the Appconfig file, there are no endpoints generated by adding service reference.
The general way to call the REST API is to directly send a request by HTTP client with the particular HTTP Verb.
Besides, IIS does not support publishing multiple interface services at the same time. Do not add multiple service contracts in the single WCF project.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.