# Call Web Service from Multi Target Project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard

Please some one can guide me, how to call ASMX service from MultiTargetProject. Below is my .proj file.

how to call ASMX Service from MultiTargetProject. I had created  **MultiTargetProjectclass type project and then add ASMX Reference**. now question is How to consume ASMX Service function from netstandard *.cs file.

I had already follow all instruction given by Microsoft but no luck. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/2.0.41">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net45;netstandard2.0;MonoAndroid90;Xamarin.iOS10;</TargetFrameworks>
        <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
        <UseFullSemVerForNuGet>false</UseFullSemVerForNuGet>
        <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net45')) ">
        <Compile Include="**\*.shared.cs" />
        <Compile Include="**\*.shared.*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netstandard')) ">
        <Compile Include="**\*.netstandard.cs" />
        <Compile Include="**\*.netstandard.*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('MonoAndroid')) ">
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" Version="71.1620.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" Version="28.0.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" Version="71.1740.0" />
        <Compile Include="**\*.android.cs" />
        <Compile Include="**\*.android.*.cs" />
        <Compile Include="**\*.androidapple.*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('Xamarin.iOS')) ">
        <Compile Include="**\*.apple.cs" />
        <Compile Include="**\*.apple.*.cs" />
        <Compile Include="**\*.androidapple.*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
            
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.4.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.4.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.4.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.4.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
            
    <ItemGroup>
        <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Reference Link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2019

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly does multi-targeting have to do with "calling an ASMX service" - by which I assume you mean making a request to an ASMX endpoint. (If you mean something else then please clarify.) The ASMX should be exposed as a URL, so you just make a HTTP request to it. There are many ways to do that, but I doubt they need to differ depending on the target framework version. have you got a specific problem with something you've tried to do in order to make the call? If so please share what you've done we can understand your issue better.

Comment: Thanks ADyson for reply. Yes I have to call ASMX Api. Above structure is Xamarin class library project structure and I have to call API (JSON Request & Response) from backend.

Comment: Ok. And the problem is...? It's not clear what's preventing you from doing so.

Comment: I had tried to Add Service Reference in above project and its added successfully.

<ItemGroup>
        <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
    </ItemGroup>

but i am unable to create object of ASMX and call API. 

Please guide.

Comment: "unable to" means what exactly? Please show what you tried and what error you get.

Comment: Did you try any of this guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Comment: e.g. I have one API Function Login. How I can call my api function. my local url is http://localhost/myapi.asmx/Login

Comment: public bool Login(string UserName, string password)
{

}

Comment: Its work fine with JQuery and ASPX Project

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide Yes, I had followed all guidelines.

Comment: Did you try to call this login method then? What went wrong? It's really unclear if you don't show your attempt or describe any errors.

Comment: Unable to create object. NameSpace.Class() obj = new NameSpace.Class(). and obj.MethodName()

Comment: Thanks for all this information but can you use the "edit" button your question to create a coherent view of the info in these various comments. Then it's much easier to understand.

Comment: Kapil, you should really spend some time setting up multi project solutions and making them work with each other. right now, the question is not clear becuase - i am guessing - you have not isolated the problem yourself.

Comment: Jay, I had asked simple question. how to call ASMX Service from MultiTargetProject. I have already mention Project Structure. If you copy above code and paste in class type project and then add ASMX Reference. now question is How to consume ASMX Service function.. Hope I have clear

Comment: ASMX is not WCF. ASMX is an almost 20 year-old obsolete and dead-end web-services platform built-in to ASP.NET WebForms back in 2001. It was deprecated by 2005 when WCF came out. WCF is built around SOAP over a variety of transports (with REST support hacked-on a few years later) while ASMX only supports SOAP over HTTP. They're really not comparable.

Comment: So my root question is: why the heck are you wanting to target an ASMX service in a greenfield project today? (I assume it's greenfield because you have what looks like an all-new client codebase). If it's a third-party service you have no control over and your client or project requires you to target it, then you should create a SOAP-over-HTTP client by hand by using `HttpClient`. The reason you can't use the auto-generated ASMX client in .NET Standard projects is because the auto-generated ASMX clients use ancient and obsolete .NET Framework 1.1 types that don't exist in .NET Standard.

Comment: We are using one apis which has ASMX Service only.

Comment: @KapilDave Have you slapped the person responsible for that service being frozen in time for 18 years with a big smelly fish?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding wsdl web reference in asp .Net Core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106617/adding-wsdl-web-reference-in-asp-net-core-project)

Comment: @Dai, as a developer we are in critical / help-less situation, after spending couple of hours, I can't found anything, so asked here on stackoverflow. if someone can help to resolve this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106617/adding-wsdl-web-reference-in-asp-net-core-project - its .net core, not multitarget class type project.